# When sliding down steep hill, is it safer to go down back or front against the hill?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Assume you are sliding down a steep hill. Is it safer to go down with your back against the hill or the front of your body against the hill? I assumed that since the surface area of your body which is touching the hill is about the the same regardless of which way you are going down, it won't make a difference. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Not enough information. Is the hill covered with ice and snow, or dirt and rocks? What equipment is used, if any? Finally, what's wrong with option C, which is don't do either one?

Comment: I think it is more important whether you are going head first or not.

Comment: Safe from what? Ground damage?  Meteor strikes?  The fence at the bottom of the hill?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft There's really only one thing anyone is ever concerned about being safe from: wild T-Rexs

Comment: There are certainly physics issues involved in this question, but as pointed out by David Hammen in a comment, there is not enough information in the question to formulate a model. If this were asked on outdoors.SE, I would have the same complaint: it's too vague to be answerable. Voting to close as not clear.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a physics question, more of something a doctor could answer. But it's usually safer to go down with your back against the hill. The reason being is that we have this thing call a rib cage, the primary purpose of which is to protect the vital organs in our torso/chest cavity. If you slide down with your front to the hill, there is less protection and you expose more of these organs to bumps, sticks, rocks, T-Rexes (T-Rexae? T-Rexi? I don't know the plural), broken glass, or other nasty and damaging things. Your back, on the other hand, is pretty much a big defence shield. It's the same reason we instinctively turn away or curl up when something threatens us; much harder to damage vitals through the back.

Beyond that, there's not much of a physics reason to prefer one over the other, this might have been a better question for Biology.SE